# Golang if/else not compiling

Tags: go

I cannot figure out why this will not compile.
It says functions ends without a return statement, but when I add a return after the else, it still won't compile.

```
func (d Foo) primaryOptions() []string{

if(d.Line == 1){
    return []string{"me", "my"}
}
else{
    return []string{"mee", "myy"}
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go forces `else` to be on the same line as the `if` brace.. because of its "auto-semicolon-insertion" rules.

So  it must be this:

```
if(d.Line == 1) {
    return []string{"me", "my"}
} else { // <---------------------- this must be up here
    return []string{"mee", "myy"}
}
```

Otherwise, the compiler inserts a semicolon for you:

```
if(d.Line == 1) {
    return []string{"me", "my"}
}; // <---------------------------the compiler does this automatically if you put it below
else {
    return []string{"mee", "myy"}
}
```

..hence your error. I will link to the relevant documentation shortly.

EDIT: [Effective Go has information regarding this](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#semicolons).